# How i can add label and search bar in Google map iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, iboutlet

I’m building an iOS app using storyboards.I integrated google map in my app and created IBOutlet of GMSMapView,search bar and label.

I dragged a search bar and label in the map screen but its not displaying when i run my app map it is displaying in the whole screen but label and search bar is not displaying.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've added it wrongly. If you want to show google map as full (height x width) of your screen, then you should first add google map, and then (above it) you've to add any other objects. In current scenario, google map view overlap your label and search bar (however its there).